# Best practice for passing multiple function arguments in C++

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, generic-programming

I am wondering what the best practice for passing multiple function arguments in C++ is. I want to follow proper generic design principles as seen in the STL.

I have a generic algorithm function. Using templates, it allows the client to select what data structure will be used for running the algorithm and what container implementation the data will be drawn from. However, in order for it to be reusable, I have selected a number of places where client-designed code should be inserted.

```
template<class CustomContainerIterator, class Queue, class Element>
void run_generic_algorithm(CustomContainerIterator container,
                           std::function<void(Element)> client_code1,
                           std::function<void(Element)> client_code2,
                           std::function<void(Element)> client_code3)
{
    Queue queue;
    //Push things iterated through onto the queue
    Element queue_element = queue.top();
    client_code1(queue_element);
    // Run code modifying queue
    client_code2(queue_element);  
    // Run code modifying queue
    client_code3(queue_element);    
}
```

The client_code() functions are specified by the client and may modify the same variables owned by the client. In my code, there are 5 client functions. I originally passed them all as lambda expressions and captured the client variables I wanted to modify. However, this makes for a very verbose function call.

Most of the time I am not even specifying all the client functions, so I have to put in a lambda function that does nothing. Is there a better way, of achieving what I want. I would like to stick to proper generic programming principles?

---

Ok so I have read the answers. Could I combine the ideas like this? Now I don't think I need virtual functions.

```
template <typename Element>
struct Customization {
    void client_code1(Element) {}
    void client_code2(Element) {}
    void client_code3(Element) {}
    void client_code4(Foo) {}
    void client_code5(Bar) {}
};

template <typename Element>
struct Implementation : public Customization {
    Data some_data;
    void client_code2(Element) {
        //Fill some_data with information.
    }
};

template<class Queue, class CustomContainerIterator, class CustomImplementation>
void run_generic_algorithm(CustomContainerIterator container,
                           CustomImplementation implementation)
{
    Queue queue;
    //Push things iterated through onto the queue
    auto queue_element = queue.top();

    implementation.client_code1(queue_element);
    // Run code modifying queue
    implementation.client_code2(queue_element);  
    // Run code modifying queue
    implementation.client_code3(queue_element);    
}
```

With usage

```
std::vector<int> v;
Implementation <int> custom;
run_generic_algorithm<std::queue<int>>(v, custom);
```

Comment: if you want to follow the stl then your method should take iterators not a container. Concerning the client functions you should show the code instead of describing it in words

Comment: You are correct. I made a mistake while writing this up. The actual code does take an iterator to a custom container.

Comment: imho you simplified the code too much. the method does not use its parameter, and its not obvious where `queue_element` or `client_code` are coming from

Comment: `pop` returns `void` and anyhow the `queue` is empty at that point

Comment: Why would queue be empty? I have only popped one element.

Comment: it is empty because you just created it one line above and calling `pop` on an empty queue will do nothing

Comment: In the comments, I am adding a bunch of things from the iterator to the queue.

Comment: then still `Element queue_element = queue.pop();` should be `Element queue_element = queue.top();` or it wont compile. `pop` returns `void`

Comment: I forgot the exact syntax of STL queue.

Comment: How is it unclear what I am asking? Two people provided satisfactory answers to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are 5 client functions.

You might pass structure instead

```
template <typename Element>
struct Customization {
    std::function<void(Element)> client_code1;
    std::function<void(Element)> client_code2;
    std::function<void(Element)> client_code3;
    std::function<void(Foo)> client_code4;
    std::function<void(Bar)> client_code5;
};
```

or even possibly an interface:

```
template <typename Element>
struct Customization {
    virtual ~Customization() = default;
    virtual void client_code1(Element) = 0;
    virtual void client_code2(Element) = 0;
    virtual void client_code3(Element) = 0;
    virtual void client_code4(Foo) = 0;
    virtual void client_code5(Bar) = 0;
};
```

and then

```
template<class Range, class Element>
void run_generic_algorithm(Range& r, const Customization <Element>& customization);
```

> Most of the time I am not even specifying all the client functions, so I have to put in a lambda function that does nothing.

With previous comment, you might give default values to the member of previous structure.

Else you can add default value to argument or create overloads.

Comment: I am not very familiar with inheritance in C++. Why would they need to be virtual.

Comment: `virtual` allows the derived class to `override` the method of the base class.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.

Comment: Would the new implementation work?

Comment: @Halbort: I fixed some typo in your new implementation and give example usage. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations to what you describe I have put the client functions into a class/struct and passed the class as either a template argument or as an instance.  (You only need to pass a class object if the functions have shared state from outside the generic function.)

I find putting the functions together in a class also makes it easier to document what the functions are responsible for inside the generic function.

```
template< class Queue >
class a_traits{
public:
   static void client_code1( Queue & );
   static void client_code2();
   static void client_code3();

};
template <class Container, class Queue, class Traits>
void run_generic_algorithm(const Container& container) {
  Queue queue;
  Traits::client_code1(queue_element);
  // Run code modifying queue
  Traits::client_code2();  
  // Run code modifying queue
  Traits::client_code3();    
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks.  did not think of passing a class.

Comment: You might want to reorder template parameter to let Container be deduced.

Comment: Passing the Traits as parameter would allow to have traits with states.

Comment: Also note that by passing a class like this makes it much easier for the compiler to do function inlining. Passing functions as objects or using virtual functions makes inlining more difficult.